# "Infering" class method arguments from any means

Tags: typescript

I have a class it has two methods and looks like this:

```
export class ResolverType {
    prompt = () => ({
        type: 'list',
        name: 'resolverType',
        message: 'Choose a resolver type:',
        choices: [
            'query',
            'mutation'
        ]
    })
    partials = (plop) => {
        plop.setPartial('resolverType', '{{ resolverType }}')
    }
}
```

This is apart of a common type of class called a `PlopPrompt`.

Each `PlopPrompt` has the same shape. They look like this:

```
import { NodePlopAPI, PlopGenerator } from 'plop';

abstract class PlopPrompt {
    abstract prompt(): PlopGenerator['prompts'][number]
    abstract partials(plop: NodePlopAPI): void
}
```

or

```
interface PlopPrompt {
    prompt(): PlopGenerator['prompts'][number]
    partials(plop: NodePlopAPI): void
}
```

or switching to `static` and using `@PlopPrompt` decorator.

```
interface PlopPromptInterface {
    prompt(): any
    partials(plop: NodePlopAPI): void
}

export function PlopPrompt() {
    return <U extends PlopPromptInterface>(constructor: U) => { constructor };
}
```

I am looking for a way to:

1. Ensure a `PlotPrompt` has these two methods.
2. Is it possible for `partials` arguments to be automatically typed? It's already defined in the definition, I don't understand why I can't see the typing and the `plop` argument comes back as `any`.

---

Not quite understanding why `plop` is typed here:

```
interface Contract {
    prompt(): any
    partials(plop: NodePlopAPI): void
}

const example: Contract = {
    prompt: () => ({
        type: 'list',
        name: 'resolverType',
        message: 'Choose a resolver type:',
        choices: [
            'query',
            'mutation'
        ]
    }),
    partials: (plop) => {
        plop.setGenerator()
        plop.setPartial('resolverType', '{{ resolverType }}')
    }
}
```

But not typed here:

```
interface Contract {
    prompt(): any
    partials(plop: NodePlopAPI): void
}

class Example extends Contract {
    prompt = () => ({
        type: 'list',
        name: 'resolverType',
        message: 'Choose a resolver type:',
        choices: [
            'query',
            'mutation'
        ]
    })
    partials = (plop) => {
        plop.setGenerator()
        plop.setPartial('resolverType', '{{ resolverType }}')
    }
}
```

Is there any way to rectify this? [I found a long conversation here, but no answers.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570)`

---

Also tried this, using anonymous class. Arguments, are still not typed.

```
const ResolverType: PlopPrompt = class {
    static prompt = () => ({
        type: 'list',
        name: 'resolverType',
        message: 'Choose a resolver type:',
        choices: [
            'query',
            'mutation'
        ]
    })
    static partials = (plop) => {
        plop.setPartial('resolverType', '{{ resolverType }}')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way that satisfies above, however `ResolverType` is not a class anymore.

I would like to understand I can have this be a class.

```
import { NodePlopAPI } from 'plop';
import { PlopPrompt } from '../shared/PlopPrompt';

interface PlopPrompt {
    prompt(): any
    partials(plop: NodePlopAPI): void
}

export const ResolverType: PlopPrompt = {
    prompt: () => ({
        type: 'list',
        name: 'resolverType',
        message: 'Choose a resolver type:',
        choices: [
            'query',
            'mutation'
        ]
    }),
    partials(plop) {
        plop.setPartial('resolverType', '{{ resolverType }}')
    }
}
```